# Occasionally SqlException: "XML parsing: illegal xml character" happens when website submitting form

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

We have a Website and in one of our page we have a form with textarea and radio buttons which submits using jQuery `$.ajax()` call to a web handler(ashx). This handler runs an SQL-UPDATE and write into an XML type field. Textarea's entered text is written to one of XML nodes and radio buttons values write to other nodes of this field. I remove illegal xml characters from entered text before submitting. In the handler I do another try to remove illegal character with `WebUtility.HtmlEncode()`.
My Problem is that in some circumstances (which I wasn't able to find) client's text entering and choosen radio button submitting will result in this error:

> SqlException: XML parsing: line 28, character 80, illegal xml character

Line number changes between 28 - 29 - 30 -31. These lines is related to that xml node which filled by submitting this form.

The error happens on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line.

I think the key is "character 80" ,this illegal character should not exist in entered text, since XML parsing error is always happens in "character 80"; and if it was on entered text it's position would changed from error to error, also I try all radio buttons, none of them result in error.
Here is an xml of a successful update of this page, what do you think this character 80 referred to:

```
<Details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <hasAwardPenalty>true</hasAwardPenalty>
  <TranslatorPayment>177800</TranslatorPayment>
  <TranslatorPaids />
  <ProofreaderPayment>53340</ProofreaderPayment>
  <FileReplace>
    <FileStatus>NONE</FileStatus>
    <AddedTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</AddedTime>
    <UploadTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</UploadTime>
    <AffectOnPayment>false</AffectOnPayment>
    <AffectOnScore>false</AffectOnScore>
  </FileReplace>
  <PaymentDetails>
    <AddedTime>2015-02-05T12:02:47.5618565+03:30</AddedTime>
    <PaymentCode>2be92023-9e69-4215-8394-1b81f5b7fc51</PaymentCode>
    <PaymentId>60508</PaymentId>
    <BankResponse>تراکنش موفق</BankResponse>
    <BankName>PASARGAD</BankName>
    <Amount>362700</Amount>
    <Status>PAID</Status>
    <AuthorityCode>6653537</AuthorityCode>
    <Type>SHETAB</Type>
    <OrderId>138587</OrderId>
  </PaymentDetails>
  <MyProperty>0</MyProperty>
  <RequestDate xsi:nil="true" />
  <TranslationPurpose>
    <Id>aa8cf8be-2e7c-42d7-8208-1721bb07299c</Id>
    <TargetCategory>OTHERS</TargetCategory>
    <TargetDescription>سایر</TargetDescription>
    <PublicationMethod>PERSONAL</PublicationMethod>
    <Tone>Formal</Tone>
    <Keynote>FluidityAndLoyality</Keynote>
    <GuidLines>با سلام و احترام و تشکر از زحمات شما لطفا مطابق رزومه جهت کافرمایان خارجی تهیه شود.</GuidLines>
    <References />
    <Modified>true</Modified>
    <AddedTime>2015-02-05T12:18:24.6859596+03:30</AddedTime>
  </TranslationPurpose>
</Details>
```

UPDATE: do you think that Window's language (Control Panel-->Language-->Change Date Time & Number -->administrator-->Language for none unicode programs) and also IIS Globalization (ASP.NET -->.NET Globalization--> File ) has any effect on this problem?

Comment: Please show us a sample `formData` in your `post` ;).

Comment: what part of xml is in the line that causing the error?

Comment: sure,  by debugging javascript , formData variable is: orderId=115385&TargetCategory=OTHERS&targetDescription=%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1&Tone=TranslatorDeside&Keynote=Fluidity&PublicationMethod=LIMITED&guidLines=+%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C+%D8%AF%D8%B1+%D8%AF%D9%84+%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D9%87+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4.&references=Salmon%3D%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%87%DB%8C+%D8%A2%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AF

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik ,since I could not find the inputs that result in error, I cannot debug to see the xml. the errors are logged.

Comment: excuse me friends, I add data classes to my post.

Comment: What is the original text for "+%D9%‌​86%D9%88%D8%B1%DB%8C‌​+%D8%AF%D8%B1+%D8%AF‌​%D9%84+%D8%AF%D8%A7%‌​D8%B4%D8%AA%D9%87+%D‌​8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4."? What did you enter in the textarea?

Comment: @ Codo: a Persian sentence: " نوری در دل داشته باش."

Comment: this illegal character should not exist in entered text, since XML parsing error is always happens in "character 80"; and if it was on entered text it's position would changed from error to error.

Comment: so I gonna change the question.

Comment: Can you log the result of `Serialize(typeof(Details), o.Details)` (no longer shown in the current version of the question) before you execute the SQL command? That would greatly help. And remove the replacement of supposedly invalid XML character in Javascript and the HTML encoding in C#. `XML.Seralization` should and will take care of this.

Comment: @Codo:  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<Details xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n<OrderId>115392</OrderId>\r\n    <TranslationPurpose>\r\n<Id>61a4d4b0-e448-436b-8963-3c9c12f25125</Id>\r\n    <TargetCategory>OTHERS</TargetCategory>\r\n    <TargetDescription>نشر محتوا</TargetDescription>\r\n    <PublicationMethod>LIMITED</PublicationMethod>\r\n <GuidLines>عجب ای دل عاشق   توهم حوصله داری\r\n</GuidLines>\r\n  <AddedTime>2017-01-02T09:29:00.4306331+03:30</AddedTime>\r\n  </TranslationPurpose>\r\n </Details>"

Comment: Thanks. This XML looks good. Is it a sample that fails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132075/discussion-between-ehsan-abidi-and-codo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manage to fix the problem with talking to our customer who gave this error, and ask him which options he had select on this page.
I managed to find illegal character ( /h001f ) in some of our html input value.

Answer (score 3):

The `XmlSerializer` class generates XML that can contain invalid XML characters (according to XML 1.0 standard). In particular, the control characters in the ASCII / Unicode range from U+0001 to U+001F (except for U+0009, U+000A and U+000D) are encoded as numeric entities by `XmlSerializer` but are illegal.

SQL Server does not accept illegal XML characters such as in this XML snippet:

```
<TargetDescription>abc&#x3;def</TargetDescription>
```

So to fix it, you can clean all strings by removing these illegal characters:

```
class XmlHelper
{
    static char[] IllegalXmlCharacters = new char[] {
        '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u0004', '\u0005', '\u0006', '\u0007',
        '\u0008', '\u000b', '\u000c', '\u000e', '\u000f', '\u0010', '\u0011',
        '\u0012', '\u0013', '\u0014', '\u0015', '\u0016', '\u0017', '\u0018',
        '\u0019', '\u001a', '\u001b', '\u001c', '\u001d', '\u001e', '\u001f'
    };

    static string RemoveIllegalXmlCharacters(string value)
    {
        string[] validParts = value.Split(IllegalXmlCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return String.Join("", validParts);
    }
}
```

To clean a string, just call the static method:

```
var cleanString = XmlHelper.RemoveIllegalXmlCharacters(dirtyString);
```

Comment: you mean Microsoft .NET 'XmlSerializer' result does not suitable for Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, if your data contains control characters that cannot be represented in XML, Microsoft .NET's `XmlSerializer` will produce output that is not suitable for SQL Server. It would be better if the `XmlSerializer` rejected the illegal control characters in the first place.

Comment: as you know I remove illegal xml characters in 2 places in my code. so my problem should not be this.